# Execute prepare statement in a sql function

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, dynamic-sql, sql-function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function2()
      RETURNS VOID
      LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
      $func$
      BEGIN
        PREPARE "my-statement7" (text, text) AS
        INSERT INTO "table" (key, a_id)
        VALUES ($1, $2);

        EXECUTE format('EXECUTE "my-statement7" (%1, %2)', 'value1', 'value2');
      END;
      $func$;
SELECT my_function2();
```

However this will return error.

I have run successfully when I do execute prepare statement in the command line but when I do it in a function it will prompt error. Somebody said the execute statement will be ambiguous in execute statement or function, so it need put execute into execute format. However, it doesn't work too.
I want to execute the prepare statement for insert because I got a lot of data got to insert in same format, but the data may need to insert to different table (also data are different), so I cannot just do insert multi or COPY for it. I think the prepare statement is the solution for me, but it cannot work in a function. This will bother me if I want to do a lot of "execute prepare statement" in a function.

Comment: "*will return error.*" - **which** error?

Answer (score 0):

[In PL/SQL, queries are already prepared and cached](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING), so you don't have to.

> As each expression and SQL command is first executed in the function, the PL/pgSQL interpreter parses and analyzes the command to create a prepared statement, using the SPI manager's SPI_prepare function. Subsequent visits to that expression or command reuse the prepared statement.

Here's how you'd write it if you tried. Note the use of `_` instead of `-` in the name to avoid quoting issues; no need to format.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function2()
      RETURNS VOID
      LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
      $func$
      BEGIN
        PREPARE my_statement7 (text, text) AS
        INSERT INTO example (key, a_id)
        VALUES ($1, $2);

        EXECUTE my_statement7( 'value1', 'value2');
      END;
      $func$;
```

However, the first time it will fail (for reasons I don't entirely understand): `ERROR:  function my_statement7(unknown, unknown) does not exist`. The second time it is called it will also fail: `ERROR:  prepared statement "my_statement7" already exists`.

Comment: The way you did I had tried before, that occurs "ERROR:  prepared statement "my_statement7" already exists." because the first time you run the function was already created the prepare statement, but the execute part is failed. The prepare statement cannot create twice with same name if you didn't deallocate the original prepare statement. However, even you remove the prepare statement from the function. "ERROR:  function my_statement7(unknown, unknown) does not exist." this will still occurs.

Comment: @JackWangb Just do the insert. No prepare, no execute.

Comment: Prepare statement for insertion seems better performance for normal insertion, so I'm trying to do this...

Comment: @JackWang Postgres prepares statements run inside a function for you.